# Mongodb aggregation distinct, average and sum with group by between two collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have **user** collection having data like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da594c15324fec81d000027"),
    "password" : "******",
    "activation" : "Active",
    "userType" : "Author",
    "email" : "something@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Something",
    "profilePicture" : "profile_pictures/5da594c15324fec81d0000271607094354423image.png",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

and On the other hand **userlogs** has data like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcb7bb4485c34a41900002b"),
    "duration" : 2.54,
    "page" : 1,
    "activityDetails" : "Viewed Page for seconds",
    "contentType" : "article",
    "activityType" : "articlePageStayTime",
    "label" : 3,
    "bookId" : ObjectId("5f93e2cc74153f8c1800003f"),
    "ipAddress" : "::1",
    "creator" : ObjectId("5da594c15324fec81d000027"),
    "created" : ISODate("2020-12-05T12:23:16.867Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

What I am trying to do is equivalent to this sql query

```
SELECT name,count(page),sum(duration),avg(DISTINCT(label)),COUNT(DISTINCT(bookId)) FROM users JOIN userlogs ON users._id=userlogs.creator where userlogs.activityType<>"articleListeningTime" group by users._id.
```

I can do normal `group by` and `sum` together.But How to do `avg distinct` and `count distinct` with this? I am using mongodb version 3.2

Comment: Do you store the password as clear text? You should not do this, store a hash value instead.

Comment: Thanks mate for the question! I am storing it as a hash value. Just replaced with asterisks after pasting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this require `$group` stage, you can use `$setUnion` and `$size`, `$avg` operators,

- `$lookup` with `userlogs` collection
- `$project` to show required fields, and filter `userlogs` as per your condition
- `$project` to get statistics from `userlogs`

  - get total logs count using `$size`
  - get total duration sum using `$sum`
  - get average of unique label using `$setUnion` and `$avg`
  - get count of unique `bookId` using `$serUnion` and `$size`

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "userlogs",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "creator",
      as: "userlogs"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      userlogs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$userlogs",
          as: "u",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$u.activityType", "articleListeningTime"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      totalCount: { $size: "$userlogs" },
      durationSum: { $sum: "$userlogs.duration" },
      labelAvg: { $avg: { $setUnion: "$userlogs.label" } },
      bookIdCount: { $size: { $setUnion: "$userlogs.bookId" } }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ThXmIeRZPv)

Comment: Thanks! It worked only after adding "as" in filter. Btw did you mean "get count of unique bookId using $setUnion and $size" in the last point?

Comment: okay "as" was optional in latest version in $filter, in last point yes it was typo i have corrected both.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think it would be possible without group by!